# Migrating Azure Key Vault secrets from one Azure subscription to another

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have multiple Azure subscriptions, and I'm working on getting the key vault from one to another. I've written a terraform program to do this. Here I'm calling the data blocks and using for each loop condition from one subscription and using the output value of those as input values in another subscription. But I'm getting the error please help. Below is the code

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "ewo1" {
  provider            = azurerm.demo-eworx-terraform-automation
  name                = "demo-eworx-keyvault"
  resource_group_name = "demo-eworx-rg"
}

output "vault_uri_ewo1" {
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault.ewo1.vault_uri
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo1" {
  provider     = azurerm.demo-eworx-terraform-automation
  for_each = toset(["demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-secret", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-tenant-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-subscription-id"])
  name         = each.key
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.ewo1.id
}

output "secret_value" {
  value     = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "ewo11" {
  provider = azurerm.terraform-automation
  name                = "demo-bteb-keyvault"
  resource_group_name = "bteb-demo-work"
}

output "vault_uri_ewo11" {
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault.ewo11.vault_uri
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11" {
  provider = azurerm.terraform-automation
  for_each = toset(["demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-secret", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-tenant-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-subscription-id"])
  name         = each.key
  value        = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.ewo11.id
}
```

I need to migrate azure key vaults secrets from one subscription to another subscription. I have written the above terraform code, I'm passing the data "azurerm_key_vault" "ewo1" output value as resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11" value input. But getting below error.

Can some check and help me in solving the issue

error message:

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
> │
> │   on demo-keyvault-migration.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11":
> │   38:   value        = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1 is object with 4 attributes
> │
> │ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
> ╵
> ╷
> │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
> │
> │   on demo-keyvault-migration.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11":
> │   38:   value        = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1 is object with 4 attributes
> │
> │ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
> ╵
> ╷
> │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
> │
> │   on demo-keyvault-migration.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11":
> │   38:   value        = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1 is object with 4 attributes
> │
> │ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
> ╵
> ╷
> │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
> │
> │   on demo-keyvault-migration.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11":
> │   38:   value        = [ for secret in data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1  : secret.name]
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1 is object with 4 attributes
> │
> ╵

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, but the primary one is related to the `azurerm_key_vault_secret` data source. You are querying the data source while using `for_each`. That means that the result will be an object with key value pairs. That is why you are getting this in the output:

> data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1 is object with 4 attributes

as in `for_each` you will use four keys:

```
for_each = toset(["demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-secret", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-client-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-tenant-id", "demo-eworx-terraform-automation-subscription-id"])
```

The easiest and probably the cleanest way to fix the error is as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ewo11" {
  provider     = azurerm.terraform-automation
  for_each     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ewo1
  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value.value
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.ewo11.id
}
```

Here it is a bit unfortunate that `each.value.value` [1] has to be used due to the attribute naming, but there is not another way. Also, please make sure you understand how the `for_each` meta-argument [2] works.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_secret#value

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: Thank you so much @Marko E. I have modified the code according to your response. Code is working now.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979

Comment: I'm able to get the Secret Values, but the Tags are not getting. Is there any way to get those details as well with for each loop.

Comment: Please ask a separate question with all the relevant details.